# Angular4 --previous page doesn't refresh when navigate back from current page

Tags: angular

Methods in Oninit function are not invoked second time  when navigate back to the same page with same route.

Comment: Please be more specific in your question, this does not help anyone give you a good answer.

Comment: Every time you load a page the variables are redeclared and the lifecycle hooks are invoked. Therefore it is obvious that the data getting lost when you are navigating back. Does that explain the problem in your situation?

Comment: This is what my exact problem I want to call the api when go back to the same page with the same route to get the latest data

Answer (score 2):

Use this implementation method

```
 import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    
    constructor(
        private routerActive:ActivatedRoute
      ) {}
    
    ngOnInit() {
        this.routerActive.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
            if (this.router.url === "/yourURL") {

              // ***** This runs whenever your page is displayed ******

            }
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Routes are cached by default, it means you should subscribe to `paramMap` and trigger loading in `subscribe` callback, if you trigger loading from constructor or lifecycle method - it will not be invoked second time.

Comment: I tried something like but it doesnt call the refreshdt method for the second time this.route.params.subscribe(
            (params: any) => {


                this.Refreshdt();
            });

Comment: I am not passing any params it is going to be the same url  route every time but I want to get the latest data

Comment: It is difficult to say anything else without component source code or plunkr.

Comment: ngOnInit() {

         this.route.params.subscribe(
             (params: any) => {

              this.dashboardsvc.getGroupsList(this.getDashboardReportUrl)
            .subscribe((data) => {
                data.forEach((m, index) => {
                    this.phasearray = JSON.parse(m.projectPhaseJson)

      }
  });
            });
  }      I have this Api call which gets data, so I want this api to be called everytime I go back to the component with the same route

Comment: Try to check network tab in chrome dev tools, if it is GET request it may be cached by browser, also try to debug code that triggers requests or add `console.log`.

Comment: yeah the get request is cached, changed api call with random url now it works, thank you.